# How to create binding service classes with JAXB2 Maven Plugin

Tags: wsdl, wsdl2java

I am trying to create a client for a ColdFusion service. Because the WSDL is using some old types, I have to use the Maven plugin maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate the classes, as described below. The issue that I have is that all I am getting is the schema objects that are defined within the WSDL. I am missing the classes that create and dispatch requests to the ColdFusion  service. Could you please help me understand how to create services classes as well?

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>wsdl-generate</id>
    <configuration>
      <schemaIncludes>
        <include>*.wsdl</include>
      </schemaIncludes>
      <catalog>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/catalog.cat</catalog>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
      <goal>generate</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <generateDirectory>src/main/coldfusion-generated</generateDirectory>
    <xnocompile>false</xnocompile>
    <extension>true</extension>
    <genJWS>true</genJWS>
    <keep>true</keep>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I wonder, can we create binding classes with JAXB2 at all? I appreciate your feedback.